# .NET WinForms Application and T-SQL

Tags: .net, winforms, t-sql, debugging

I tried to start my winforms application without the debugger and attach Visual studio debugger to the process afterwards. At this point my application process shows up as "T-SQL and 4.0 x86". Searching on google I see that T-SQL is regarding Microsoft SQL Server. I use a third party dll and linq sequences but i dont use any SQL server. I also use the GeckoFX Browser in my application.

When i navigate in Debugger Attach Process there is a message SPAM with content :    `0x000006BA: RPC server is unavailable`

1. How come my app is tagged as a T-SQL app?
2. How can i find if a third party dll uses T-SQL ?
3. What does  "0x000006BA: RPC server is unavailable" means?
4. How can I get the debugger to correctly attach to my process?

I checked in the Windows Services and RPC server is started.

Comment: For #2, I found [this article](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-sfc-error-0x000006ba-rpc-unavailable/). I can't test it right now, so I'll just say that other than being annoying, AFAIK it's OK to ignore this message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is always shown -- even if your application does nothing with MS SQL Server.
2. "RPC server" message is not a service name -- it means that server you try to make call to is unavailable. I guess VS debugger uses RPC (that is btw remote procedure call) to connect somewhere for its needs.